# Issue when press in tooltips don't work for (iOS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I Create a directive using angular JS.
I can display the tooltips in the android, ios but not

Comment: i have displaying the tooltips, but now when i press outside , the tooltip don't close. Do not prevent popup from closing when you click outside popup

Comment: it will not hide on lose focus: <button tabindex="0" data-trigger="focus" popover-placement="right" popover="On the Right!" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>